# Foreach PHP JSON json_decode Como imprimir sub array

Tags: php, json, foreach

Bom dia pessoal! A minha dúvida é o seguinte. Criei um foreach para acessar os dados abaixo de uma API

```
$token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

$headers = array('Authorization: Token ' . $token);

$ch_subs = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch_subs, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://dominio.site.com/api/listar');
curl_setopt($ch_subs, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch_subs, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch_subs, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$obj_json_trans = json_decode(curl_exec($ch_subs));{
"total": 1,
"eventos": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "status": "em andamento",
        "titulo": "Evento Demo",
        "descricao": "Apenas um evento de teste",
        "logomarca_hotsite": "http://",
        "logomarca_evento": "http://",
        "data_inicio": "10/02/2018",
        "data_termino": "11/02/2018",
        "participantes": {
            "totais": 10,
            "confirmados": "5",
            "nao_confirmados": "3",
            "desativados": "2"
        },
        "link_hotsite": "http://",
        "link_evento": "http://",
        "link_inscricao": "http://",
    }   ] }      $eventos = $obj_json_trans->eventos;      
        foreach ( $eventos as $e )
        {
            echo "id: $e->id - status: $e->status - título: $e->titulo<br>";                 
        }
        curl_close($ch_subs);
```

Eu consigo imprimir os arrays mas não sei como imprimir o sub array "participantes".
Alguém sabe como fazer para eu conseguir também imprimir o sub array

```
"participantes": {
        "totais": 10,
        "confirmados": "5",
        "nao_confirmados": "3",
        "desativados": "2"
    },
```

Veja o código completo

```
<?php

$token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

$headers = array('Authorization: Token ' . $token);

$ch_subs = curl_init();


curl_setopt($ch_subs, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://site.com/api/listar');
curl_setopt($ch_subs, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch_subs, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

curl_setopt($ch_subs, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$obj_json_trans = json_decode(curl_exec($ch_subs));


/* print_r($obj_json_trans); */

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        $eventos = $obj_json_trans->eventos;    
        foreach ( $eventos as $chave=>$e )
        {
            echo "id: $e->id - status: $e->status - título: $e->titulo <br> ";                  

        }

        curl_close($ch_subs);
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Faltam te os ' [ ' parênteses rectos nos participantes para coloca-los como vector. De seguida faz o mesmo processo dos eventos e deve imprimir... Que dizes?

Comment: Na api que estou puxando vem igual ao modelo debaixo
 {
 "total": 1,

 "eventos": [
  {
   "id": "1",
   "status": "em andamento",
   "titulo": "Evento Demo",
   "descricao": "Apenas um evento de teste",
   "logomarca_hotsite": "http://",
   "logomarca_evento": "http://",
   "data_inicio": "10/02/2018",
   "data_termino": "11/02/2018",
   "participantes": {
    "totais": 10,
    "confirmados": "5",
    "nao_confirmados": "3",
    "desativados": "2"
   },
   "link_hotsite": "http://",
   "link_evento": "http://",
   "link_inscricao": "http://",
  }
 ]
}

Comment: @leodario edite a sua questão e coloque lá o seu código, senão fica difícil de perceber.

Comment: cloquei o código completo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá,

Prefiro trabalhar com Arrays! Colocando true no segundo parâmetro da json_decode( $json, true). [json_decode - PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php)

```
$eventos = $obj_json_trans[ 'eventos' ];

// LOOP EVENTOS
foreach ( $eventos as $k => $v ) {

    // MOSTRA OS VALORES COM QUEBRA DE LINHA
    echo "$k - $v <br>";

    // SE CHAVE É PARTICIPANTES E É ARRAY, LOOP E MOSTRA OS PARTICPANTES
    if($k === 'participantes' && is_array($v)){

        // LOOP PARTICIPANTES
        foreach($v as $k2 => $v2){

            echo "- $k2 = $v2 <br>";

        } // LOOP PARTICPANTES

    } // IF PARTICPANTES

} // LOOP EVENTOS
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($eventos as $e) {
  echo "id: $e->id - status: $e->status - título: $e->titulo<br>";
  foreach ($e->participantes as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key: $value <br>";                 
  }
}
```